# Restrict method on MultiActionController action

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `MultiActionController` with an action that I would only like to be reachable if the  `POST` method is used.

```
public class MyController extends MultiActionController {

  public ModelAndView myAction(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    // I don't want to hit this code unless POST was used
  }

}
```

Is there a way to achieve this through annotations or am I stuck checking `request.getMethod()` ?

Comment: `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Comment: @JigarJoshi I know if I use the `@Controller` annotation that's one way to get there, but what about if I want to `extend MultiActionController` still?

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"action1","action2","action3"}, 
    method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.